# SAS running batch mode issue

Tags: sas

I asked this question before but that time the issue was that I had blanks in my directory, which SAS somehow did not like. This time I do not have any blank in my directory but batch run is not working for me. It either keeps on running (the DOS screen keeps rolling) or no output. I don't get any error in my log and can run in the program but not in batch.
Can anyone have idea?

batch code:

```
data _null_;
 file "C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\PIE.bat";
 put 'C:';
 put "CD C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\";
 put "PIE_wc(v1.1) C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\ABCA05Cv0.txt   C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\ABCA05COUTv0.txt";
RUN;

options xmin noxwait;
x "C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\PIE.bat";
```

Comment: I just noticed that the name of exe file of PIE program is actually PIE_wc(v1.1).exe. So I copied and pasted as it is until exe. But still I don't get any result....

Comment: What happens if you run the generated PIE.bat from a normal DOS prompt? It's unclear from your post whether this works, or whether you can run PIE_wc itself manually. I'm not sure you would expect any error in the SAS log, SAS will just launch a command window and execute the PIE.bat file.

Comment: I can run PIE manually. The bat file I made pie.bat is not running by itself. Also it does not run in SAS either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work in batch mode. I just changed the exe file name into PIE. Instead of putting PIE_wc(v1.1) in the batch code, some how PIE worked.

Comment: By the way renaming in the data step did not work. It did not like paranethesis PIE program had.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your BAT file to put double-quotes around the parameters:

```
data _null_;  
   file 'C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\PIE.bat';  
   put 'C:';  
   put 'CD C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\';  
   put '"PIE_wc(v1.1).exe" "C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\ABCA05Cv0.txt" "C:\Users\ubishky\Documents\ABCA05COUTv0.txt"';
RUN;
```

You might also want to give the complete path to whatever that program is.  Also, note that I replaced all the double-quotes in your program with single-quotes.  You should always only use single-quotes when defining character values.  Double-quoted strings will be evaluated by the SAS Macro processor and might lead to othe proble